# PleaseWaitButton in perl? loading gif etc. during long sql query

Tags: sql, database, perl, user-interface, loading

I have a web app that is all run via one perl file that works with a database. At one point the user can execute an action that takes a lot of time (it adds a bunch of rows from one table to another). Is there a way I can have a wait .gif or message show while the sql is executing, and then have it disappear once it's over?  I'm pretty new to perl, saw that this was possible through Javascript and the PleaseWaitButton though. Any help would be much appreciate though.  My code for the lengthy update part is below, so I image whatever thing would need to be inserted somewhere in there:

```
if((@inTable[0])==0){
my $update = `perl /stockhistory.pl
my @updatearray = split(" ", $update);
my $val;
for(my $i = 0; $i < scalar @updatearray; $i+=6){
    $val = eval{ExecSQL($dbuser, $dbpasswd, "insert into PORT_ModernData (SYMBOL, TIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",undef, $stocksy,, $updatearray[$i], $updatearray[$i+1], $updatearray[$i+2], $updatearray[$i+3], $updatearray[$i+4], $updatearray[$i+5]);};
}
}
```

Thanks for any and all help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I understand your problem, I would suggest Javascript, though I do like avoiding it myself.

This way, the user can click the button, triggering the sql get, and the message comes up, while the server does what it does, when done, Javascript can tell the user so and provide the link, data or whatever the result is.

With perl, this would involve a more complicated procedure including further server/client communication.

I would gladly be corrected, though, if anyone knows better.

Comment: Javascript might be the answer, I'll accept your answer if no one posts something else in the next day or so